# APK error when publishing android app with firebase

Tags: firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, apk

I made an app in android and connect it with cloud firebase and created database for questions and answers but when I was about to publish, it shows apk file error I didn't change my package name from com.example as I didn't know about that now I made a new cloud firebase and connect it with app after changing package name but I don't have all data in it please is their a solution to copy all data or use that same firebase app?

Comment: Can you give some more details on the error please? Exactly where do you see the error, and exactly what does it say. From what you have written, it is very hard to know the exact error

Comment: When you add all file in it but don't change package name from com.example it says your package name should be unique so I changed my package name and therefore made new firebase with that package name and lost all database